# installing the python IDLE on linux

Tags: linux, python-3.x

i just want to install python IDLE  on my LINUX can any one please help with this how to install this Idle(shell)  on my operating system?

Answer (score 0):

on ubuntu you can do this by running that command:

```
sudo apt-get install idle3
```

for python2 use only idle instead of idle3